# How do I get a UIButton pointer?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

How do I get a UIButton pointer from a button I created with a tag?

```
int buttonTagIndex = button.tag;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what I'm using in a UIViewController to get it done.

```
UIButton *btn = (UIButton *) [self.view viewWithTag:index];
```